# Showing Model Predictions with Shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

I'd be happy to get some help with R shiny, I'm new to it.
I built a logistic regression model that runs on a training set called "Rdata1.csv".
Then after I train the model I want let the user upload a test set file 
and run the predictions on the test set.

Here is my ui.R:

```
 library(shiny)
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Predictions"),

 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file", label = h3("Upload CSV")),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
  ),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("text1")
)
)
))
```

Here is my server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(aod)
library(ROCR)

mydata <- read.csv("C:/Rdata1.csv")
mydata$Continent <- factor(mydata$Continent)
mydata$IP <- factor(mydata$IP)

mylogit <- glm(Good ~ Continent + IP, data = mydata, family = "binomial")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$text1 <- renderPrint({ 
 mydatanew <- read.csv(input$file[4])
 mydatanew$Continent <- factor(mydatanew$Continent)
 mydatanew$IP <- factor(mydatanew$IP)
 mydatanew$predicted<-predict(mylogit, newdata=mydatanew, type="response")
 paste("predictions", mydatanew)
  })

 }
 )
```

In the app I get no output - instead it I get the error:
"file must be a character string or connection" and i see nothing.
Anyone know what's wrong with the code?
Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used windows R in a while... but are the slashes the correct way in the file name, and you might have to escape them... it might be "C:\Rdata1.csv" or "C:\\Rdata1.csv"

Comment: Hi,Yes they are correct the script alone works well but with shiny it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  This question is hard to make reproducible, but it looks like the `datapath` from `fileInput` is not being passed correctly.  See `?fileInput`:

```
Whenever a file upload completes, the corresponding input variable is set to a dataframe. 
This dataframe contains one row for each selected file, and the following columns: ...
```

... the fourth of which is `datapath`.

In other words

```
file <- data.frame(name="foo",size=999,type="text/plain",datapath = "~/temp/whatever.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(file[4]) # this gives you a little data frame, probably not what you want
str(file[1,4]) # this gives you the character value itself
```

Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i tried replacing file[4] with file[1,4] and it didn't work